# Group files in some folders

Tags: filemanager, file-format

I have some files with different extensions such as `*.pdf`, `*.mp3`, `*.jpg` and a few others. All of them are stored in a `parent` directory.

How can I get a list of all extensions, create some folders based on these  extensions and then move all files into their relevant folders?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The python script below does the job. Hidden files are stored separately in a folder
, as well as files without extension.

Since it might be used for a wider range of purposes, I added a few options:

- You can set extensions you'd like to exclude from the "reorganization". If you simply want to move all, set `exclude = ()`
- You can choose what to do with empty folders (`remove_emptyfolders = True` or `False`)
- In case you would like to *copy* the files instead of *moving* them, replace the line:

```python
shutil.move(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)
```

by:

```python
shutil.copy(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)
```

The script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/path/to/directory_to_reorganize"
exclude = (".jpg") # for example
remove_emptyfolders = True
# ---------------------------------------------------------

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        if name.startswith("."):
            extension = ".hidden_files"
        elif not "." in name:
            extension = ".without_extension"
        else:
            extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
        if not extension in exclude:
            new_dir = reorg_dir+"/"+extension[1:]
            if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
            shutil.move(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)

def cleanup():
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
        for name in files:
            filelist.append(root+"/"+name)
    directories = [item[0] for item in os.walk(reorg_dir)]
    for dr in directories:
        matches = [item for item in filelist if dr in item]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dr)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

if remove_emptyfolders == True:
    cleanup()
```

**IF there is a risk of unwanted overwriting duplicate files**

At the expense of a few extra lines, we can prevent overwriting possible duplicates. With the code below, duplicates will be renamed as:

```python
duplicate_1_filename, duplicate_2_filename
```

etc.

The script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/path/to/directory_to_reorganize"
exclude = (".jpg") # for example
remove_emptyfolders = True
# ---------------------------------------------------------

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        if name.startswith("."):
            extension = ".hidden_files"
        elif not "." in name:
            extension = ".without_extension"
        else:
            extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
        if not extension in exclude:
            new_dir = reorg_dir+"/"+extension[1:]
            if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
            n = 1; name_orig = name
            while os.path.exists(new_dir+"/"+name):
                name = "duplicate_"+str(n)+"_"+name_orig
                n = n+1
            newfile = new_dir+"/"+name
            shutil.move(subject, newfile)

def cleanup():
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
        for name in files:
            filelist.append(root+"/"+name)
    directories = [item[0] for item in os.walk(reorg_dir)]
    for dr in directories:
        matches = [item for item in filelist if dr in item]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dr)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

if remove_emptyfolders == True:
    cleanup()
```

---

### EDIT

With OP in mind, we all forgot to add an instruction on how to use. Since duplicate questions might ([and do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716907/sort-file-into-directories-base-on-their-extension?noredirect=1#comment1058262_716907)) appear, it might be useful nevertheless.

#### How to use

1. Copy either one of the scripts into an empty file, save it as `reorganize.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the targeted directory (with the files to reorganize):

   ```python
   reorg_dir = "/path/to/directory_to_reorganize"
   ```

   (use quotes if the directory contains spaces)

   possible extensions you'd like to exclude (probably none, like below):

   ```python
   exclude = ()
   ```

   and if you'd like to remove empty folders afterwards:

   ```python
   remove_emptyfolders = True
   ```
3. Run the script with the command:

   ```python
   python3 /path/to/reorganize.py
   ```

**NB** if you'd like to *copy* the files instead of *move*, replace:

```python
shutil.move(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)
```

by:

```python
shutil.copy(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)
```

Please try first on a small sample.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `find` with a somewhat complex `exec` command:

```bsh
find . -iname '*?.?*' -type f -exec bash -c 'EXT="${0##*.}"; mkdir -p "$PWD/${EXT}_dir"; cp --target-directory="$PWD/${EXT}_dir" "$0"' {} \;

# '*?.?*' requires at least one character before and after the '.', 
# so that files like .bashrc and blah. are avoided.
# EXT="${0##*.}" - get the extension
# mkdir -p $PWD/${EXT}_dir - make the folder, ignore if it exists
```

Replace `cp` with `echo` for a dry run.

---

More efficient and tidier would be to save the `bash` command in a script (say, at  `/path/to/the/script.sh`):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i
do
    EXT="${i##*.}" 
    mkdir -p "$PWD/${EXT}_dir"
    mv --target-directory="$PWD/${EXT}_dir" "$i" 
done
```

And then run `find`:

```
find . -iname '*?.?*' -type f -exec /path/to/the/script.sh {} +
```

This approach is pretty flexible. For example, to use the filename instead of the extension (`filename.ext`), we'd use this for `EXT`:

```
NAME="${i##*/}"
EXT="${NAME%.*}"
```

Comment: +1; the `-iname '*.*'` should take care of the corner cases I was worried about... nice idea!

Comment: @Rmano not the `*.fig.bak` or `.profile/.bashrc` ones, but it should only handle files with extensions, at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
ls | gawk -F. 'NF>1 {f= $NF "-DIR"; system("mkdir -p " f ";mv " $0 " " f)}'
```

Calculating the list of extensions (after moving):

```
ls -d *-DIR
```

Calculating the list of extensions (before moving):

```
ls -X | grep -Po '(?<=\.)(\w+)$'| uniq -c | sort -n
```

(in this last exemple, we are calculating the number of files for each extension and sorting it)

Comment: sorry: a typo "mkdir -f" was corrected to "mkdir -p" (to ignore if dir already exist)

Comment: Isn't uniq supposed to be applied after sort? And please do not parse the output of ls.

Comment: @muru, (part 1) ls -X guarantees that extensions are sorted. Final sort was just to order the extensions table by number of occurrences -- relevance. (I'm I correct?).

Comment: @muru, (part 2) `ls -X | grep -Po '(?<=\.)(\w+)$'` was my first idea to get the sorted list of extensions. Is it very bad? What do you suggest?

Comment: I forgot what `ls -X` does. As to why I recommend against `ls`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/70524 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112125/70524. To achieve what you do, I'd go about a longer way: `find . -type f -name '*?.?*' -print0 | sed -z 's/.*\.//' | sort -zu` (with an optional `| uniq -cz`, if counts are needed). And `find ... -print0 | gawk -v RS='\0'` (even though that is [not very portable](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html#index-sidebar_002c-RS-_003d-_0022_005c0_0022-Is-Not-Portable)) for the first.

Comment: @muru, Thank you, i see your point. We have to ask for a `ls -z` :)

Comment: @JJoao Anthon over at U&L submitted a patch for it, and it was rejected.

Comment: @muru, we have to insist! :) (happy new year!)

Answer (score 5):

Try this shell script.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
src=`dirname "$1"`/`basename "$1"`;
for file in "$src"/*?.?*; do
  if test -f "$file"; then
    dest="$src${file##*.}"_files;
    mkdir -p "$dest";
    mv "$file" "$dest";
  fi;
done;

# pass the directory to re-organize as first argument
# moves only regular files which have extension
# ignores other type of files including
# files having no extension, hidden files, directories, and links.
```

Comment: I am sorry, that is an error. I should have to substituted every occurrence of `filepath` with `file`. I'll correct that directly.

Comment: Please do not parse the output of ls. Instead, do `for file in "$src"/*?.?*; do ..`

Comment: @muru will that work correctly if the name of some file has spaces?

Comment: @PrashantKarmakar yes, whereas `read` may have unexpected behaviour. You should also be quoting the variables in the mkdir and mv commands.

Comment: Test it out, if you will: `for i in *; do printf "%s\n" "$i"; done; for i in $(ls -d); do printf "%s\n" "$i"; done`

Comment: I did . `$ touch "ho ho"; for i in *; do echo $i; done` worked correctly. Thank You. I will improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Perl's rename/prename installed:

```
rename 's!(.*)\.(\w+)$! mkdir($2); "$2/$&"!ge'  *
```