# Sort file into directories base on their extension

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, data-recovery, filemanager

I just recovered more than 2 Million files using PhotoRect, the files in the recovery folder contain more than 2 Thousand folder containing random files extension .

It would be impossible if I sort them manually, I tried to program a bash script but I found this on the INTERNET:

```
 #/bin/sh

# Give directory as argument
dir=$1
if [ "x$dir" != "x" -a -d "$dir" ] ; then
  cd "$dir"
fi

dir=$(pwd)
basedir=$(basename "$dir")

exts=$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | grep '^\./.*\.' | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.][^.]*\)$/\1/' | sort -u)

for e in $exts; do

   # Skip extension if this directory is already named by extension.
   if [ "$basedir" = "$e" ] ; then
      continue
   fi

   mkdir "$e"
   for file in *.$e; do
      mv "$file" "$e"
   done
done
```

It's usage is `find . -depth -type d -print -exec /path/to/ext/script {} \;`

This script get through the sub-directories in the main directory and creating folders in the directory with the name of the extension of the file

For example :   `folder1` is our main directory

```
 folder1                     It becomes  =>      folder1
 --- subFolder1                                  -- subFolder1
    -------file11.php                               ----php
    ------file12.txt                                      file11.php
    -------file13.img                                     file14.php
    -------file14.php                               ----img
 --- subFolder2                                           file13.img
    -------file21.php                              
    ------file22.txt                                And So On....
    -------file23.img
    -------file24.php
 --- subFolder3
    -------file31.php
    ------file32.txt
    -------file33.img
    -------file34.php
```

But I want it to create another directory `newFolder` which contains all file with php extension in all the directories and sub directories .

Is that possible, I don't have that much of experience in bash .

Comment: The dupe can save you some time...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I didn't understand what that script do exactly, does it go to every sub directory ?

Comment: yup, it does :)

Comment: Oh, thanks ^^ but please how can I implement it ?

Comment: I will add an instruction there ...

Comment: Oh, so you wrote the answer, :D what an honor ! Thanks !

Comment: No sure, the python scripts are mine, did you mean that one?

Comment: I meant the python script.

Comment: ...Done! Please mention if anything is unclear.

Comment: That *does* make me happy :)