# Showing all installed programs in Ubuntu

Tags: launcher, desktop-environments, .desktop, installed-programs

In Ubuntu, where to see all programs just like the "program files" in windows, from which I can launch a program from a list of all program installed?

Comment: Probably software center is best, although there is no equivalent of "program files" in linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to launch applications from the list a nice option is **Classic Gnome indicator.**

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

[image]

See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/189929/how-to-install-and-launch-the-classic-gnome-menu-in-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: It does work on Unity. It is intended for Unity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I install it in my superuser account. However, it only shows a very small part of the pragrams. Interstingly, it works perfectly in my other normal user account and shows all the programs as shown in your figure. Do you have any idea why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe, the Main Menu entries should be edited. Try searching it from the list of the apps.

Comment: Thanks Muzaffar, one more thing, how to uninstall it, just in case I want to later?

Comment: Thanks Muzaffar, one more thing, how to uninstall it, just in case I want to later?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge classicmenu-indicator

Answer (score 8):

## Just for fun

Since OP mentioned: *from which I can launch a program from a list of all program installed?*

Below a small script that lists **all** (globally) installed GUI applications. Choose one to launch it, or type a few of its characters and press <kbd>Return</kbd> to run the application:

[image]

#### To use

- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `list_apps.py`
- Test- run it by the command (open a terminal window, type the command and press <kbd>Return</kbd>):

  ```
  python3 /path/to/list_apps.py
  ```
- If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
  python3 /pat/to/list_apps.py
  ```

  to a shortcut key combination you like.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

dr = "/usr/share/applications"

apps = []

for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]:
    try:
        content = open(dr+"/"+f).read()
        if not "NoDisplay=true" in content:
            lines = content.splitlines()
            name = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Name=")][0].replace("Name=", "")
            command = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Exec=")][0].replace("Exec=", "")
            apps.append([name, command])
    except:
        pass

apps.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]); apps = sum(apps, [])
displ_list = '"'+'" "'.join(apps)+'"'

try:
    chosen = subprocess.check_output([
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        'zenity --list '+\
        '--column="Applications" '+\
        '--column="commands" '+\
        '--hide-column=2 --height 450 '+\
        '--width 300 '+\
        '--print-column=2 '+displ_list
        ]).decode("utf-8").split("|")[-1].strip()
    chosen = chosen[:chosen.rfind(" ")] if "%" in chosen else chosen
    subprocess.Popen([
        "/bin/bash", "-c", chosen
        ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

#### How it works

The script lists all `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`, and checks if the line `NoDisplay=true` is in the file (which means it is not meant to be used as a GUI). Then it looks into the files, looks up the application name and the command to run it.

The result is listed in a `zenity` list, to choose from. If you pick one, the corresponding command is executed.

That's it.

---

#### Extended version

If you also would like to have a short description on the application, As mentioned in the `Comment=` line of its `.desktop` file, use the version below:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

dr = "/usr/share/applications"

apps = []

for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]:
    try:
        content = open(dr+"/"+f).read()
        if not "NoDisplay=true" in content:
            lines = content.splitlines()
            name = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Name=")][0].replace("Name=", "")
            command = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Exec=")][0].replace("Exec=", "")
            comment = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Comment=")]
            comment = comment[0].replace("Comment=", "") if comment else "No description"
            apps.append([name, command, comment])
    except:
        pass

apps.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]); apps = sum(apps, [])
displ_list = '"'+'" "'.join(apps)+'"'

try:
    chosen = subprocess.check_output([
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        'zenity --list '+\
        '--column="Applications" '+\
        '--column="commands" '+\
        '--column="Description" '+\
        '--hide-column=2 --height 450 '+\
        '--width 500 '+\
        '--print-column=2 '+displ_list
        ]).decode("utf-8").split("|")[-1].strip()
    chosen = chosen[:chosen.rfind(" ")] if "%" in chosen else chosen
    subprocess.Popen([
        "/bin/bash", "-c", chosen
        ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

Comment: A KISS solution: Keep it Simply Stupid!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Haha, I really need to add that one to my repertoire :)

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu not all the program are listed in the application menu.

To see them all you will need to **open a console**
and type

```
dpkg -l
```

This will display all application (the one which run in the UI and the one running in the console)

Comment: No, that displays the list of software *packages* that are installed.  Many packages ( especially those that contain command line programs ) contain multiple applications, and many packages contain none ( they are libraries or data files used by other applications ).