# How to stop opening an application exit you out of the Activities Overview?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, gnome-shell-extension, activities-overview

I often need to go into the Activities Overview and open many applications so it is rather annoying if every time I click to open an application I am taken out of the AO and to that application, though this is useful on some occasions, I would prefer to stay in the AO and whatever part of it I am in.

Can this be done? Perhaps there is an extension to achieve this? Preferably I would like to be able to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> click or something on an application in order to open it but not take me out of the AO, so that it is easier for me when I don't need it.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: As mentioned by @Serg (thanks!), I could alter the code of this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/606252/72216, give it a Gtk window etc. Please mention if that would suite. I am home irregularly a t m however, so it might take a while...

Comment: Hi Paranoid, the question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/717731/showing-all-installed-programs-in-ubuntu turned out to be a better candidate for editing than the one above ^. Please let me know if you manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already such functionality to do this, simply <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CLICK</kbd> an item (e.g.: application, file, etc) in the Activities Overview in order to open it but not to also close the AO.

Answer (score 2):

An slightly edited version of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/717796/72216) allows multiple selection of applications at once:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

dr = "/usr/share/applications"

apps = []

for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]:
    try:
        content = open(dr+"/"+f).read()
        if not "NoDisplay=true" in content:
            lines = content.splitlines()
            name = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Name=")][0].replace("Name=", "")
            command = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Exec=")][0].replace("Exec=", "")
            comment = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("Comment=")]
            comment = comment[0].replace("Comment=", "") if comment else "No description"
            apps.append([name, command, comment])
    except:
        pass

apps.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]); apps = sum(apps, [])
displ_list = '"'+'" "'.join(apps)+'"'

try:
    chosen = subprocess.check_output([
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        'zenity --list '+\
        '--multiple '+\
        '--column="Applications" '+\
        '--column="commands" '+\
        '--column="Description" '+\
        '--hide-column=2 --height 450 '+\
        '--width 500 '+\
        '--print-column=2 '+displ_list
        ]).decode("utf-8").split("|")
    for item in chosen:
        item = item.strip()
        item = item[:item.rfind(" ")] if "%" in item else item
        subprocess.Popen([
            "/bin/bash", "-c", item
            ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

#### To use

- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `list_apps.py`
- Test- run it by the command (open a terminal window, type the command and press <kbd>Return</kbd>):

  ```
  python3 /path/to/list_apps.py
  ```
- If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
  python3 /pat/to/list_apps.py
  ```

  to a shortcut key combination you like.

#### Explanation

The script lists all `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`, and checks if the line `NoDisplay=true` is in the file (which means it is not meant to be used as a GUI). Then it looks into the files, looks up the application name and the command to run it.

The difference with the linked answer is mainly the fact that the zenity window is set to allow *multiple selections*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I found out a built-in way to do this so I have also posted that as an answer. But thanks for this! It will come in handy on other DEs!